# NoSuchFieldError Exception in Stanford NER

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm using the Stanford NER, and whenever I try to initialize the classifier I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: featureFactoryArgs
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.<init>(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:127)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.<init>(CRFClassifier.java:173)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.getClassifierNoExceptions(CRFClassifier.java:3518)
```

My code:

```
String serializedClassifier = "classifiers/english.all.3class.caseless.distsim.crf.ser.gz";
        AbstractSequenceClassifier<CoreLabel> classifier =
                CRFClassifier.getClassifierNoExceptions(serializedClassifier);
```

Comment: This exception is driving me like crazy! 4 hours without any luck to identify what's wrong!

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't a problem with Stanford NER. The problem was another library (CMU TweetNLP) hiding an outdated copy of various Stanford NLP classes inside their jar, unleashing [jar hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader#JAR_hell).